# Cached list of data from database in .NET Framework 4

Tags: c#, .net, database, caching

I have an application that uses data from a table which is almost always not changing in many parts of it.
This seems a right place to make a cache of it. So: i need to make cached list of that data to work with it, but have some expiration timeout after which my cached list should update itself from database(thats why global static list is not for this situation).

**PS** im sure thats not that difficult, but im new to caching and help will save my time, thank you. At least i can create static list that will be updated after some timeout with timer in another thread, but i think such solution is too ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of hints here on how to achieve that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997357.aspx

Cache can be fitted with an expiry date so it will go and re-fetch the data after a set amount of time without dealing with timers etc.

Comment: And how to update cache after some time?..There are some ChangeMonitors, but how to launch event after some time(expiration timeout), for example, without timers..?

Comment: My list, whose cache i want to use will be smth like this: Entity context = new Entity(); var cacheList = context.Dictionaries.ToList();  (i use EF here to get data, so i'll need to requery DB after expiration time)

Comment: You don't - it updates when you read and the cache timeout has expired.  To implement, you store a date that the data was fetched originally.  Every time you go and read from the cache, you check the current date aginst it and if a predetermined time has elapsed you go and fetch it again and regenerate the cached copy.

Comment: Don't ever cache data from an ORM directly!  Transform it into POCOs first otherwise any context that is carried in the objects by the ORM will not be available after the copy is recovered from the cache leading to odd crashes.

Comment: Why not?..For this cache i need just list of property values. I dont need to cache database with that cache or smth. Just updatable `List<Dictionary>` in my case.